# SQL Select recursively in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I do have a table with that structure:

**pedido_venda_restaurante**:

- `idpedido_venda_restaurante`, Index PK
- `idpedido_venda_restaurante_principal`, FK (points to `idpedido_venda_restaurante` of the same table)
- `codigo_pv_interno` VarChar UNIQUE

---

I made a query which's objective is by the `codigo_pv_interno` typed by the user the query should return all the rows that:

- Have the `codigo_pv_interno` typed;
- Have the `idpedido_venda_restaurante_principal` equals to `idpedido_venda_restaurante_principal` of the row where `codigo_pv_interno` was typed;
- Have the `idpedido_venda_restaurante_principal` equals to `idpedido_venda_restaurante` of the row where `codigo_pv_interno` was typed;

That means that the query should return, himself, the children (if exist), the father (if exists) and the brothers (if exist)

```
SELECT
    idpedido_venda_restaurante
    ,codigo_pv_interno
    ,idpedido_venda_restaurante_principal
FROM pedido_venda_restaurante
WHERE idpedido_venda_restaurante IN (SELECT
        pedido_origem.idpedido_venda_restaurante
    FROM pedido_venda_restaurante AS pedido_origem
    WHERE pedido_origem.codigo_pv_interno = '003')
OR idpedido_venda_restaurante IN (SELECT
        idpedido_venda_restaurante
    FROM pedido_venda_restaurante
    WHERE idpedido_venda_restaurante_principal = (SELECT
            idpedido_venda_restaurante_principal
        FROM pedido_venda_restaurante
        WHERE codigo_pv_interno = '003'))
OR idpedido_venda_restaurante IN (SELECT
        idpedido_venda_restaurante
    FROM pedido_venda_restaurante
    WHERE idpedido_venda_restaurante = (SELECT
            idpedido_venda_restaurante_principal
        FROM pedido_venda_restaurante
        WHERE codigo_pv_interno = '003'))
OR idpedido_venda_restaurante_principal = (SELECT
        pedido_origem.idpedido_venda_restaurante
    FROM pedido_venda_restaurante AS pedido_origem
    WHERE pedido_origem.codigo_pv_interno = '003');
```

Actually this query already works and returns the desired result but due to my low knowledge of SQL I do think that should exist an efficient way to do it.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can use INNER JOIN to check If the elements exist in the table:

```
SELECT pvr.idpedido_venda_restaurante, pvr.codigo_pv_interno, pvr.idpedido_venda_restaurante_principal
FROM pedido_venda_restaurante pvr
INNER JOIN pedido_venda_restaurante as pedido_origem
ON pedido_origem.idpedido_venda_restaurante  = pvr.idpedido_venda_restaurante
WHERE pvr.pedido_origem.codigo_pv_interno = '003'
```

Repeat the process with the other tables where you want to search the value